# How to classify matrix data in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, classification, svm, multilabel-classification

Usually classification algorithms work with feature vectors but in this case I need to work with matrices of features. 


My data set consists of 50 matrices (sizes of matrices: ***N x 4***, where 4 is a number of features. Number of rows ***N*** is different for every matrix). There are 5 classes, one matrix characterize one class (so in my case 10 matrices belong to one class). 


How to work with this input data? I am going to classify this data set using SVM. So it will be very helpful if you'll recomend how to work with my input data for this algorithm.

Comment: Yes, it's called Bag-of-words.  Check this post on Cross Validated for a bit more detail: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90480/how-to-give-the-input-of-an-image-to-svm-after-preprocessing .  Also, these Wiki articles are a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model